# looking for swap partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

How do I know I have a swap partition or not? I have a dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8. During Ubuntu installation steps I choice "Install Ubuntu alongside windows 8" option. Does swap partition is created automatically by installation or not? if it's not created how can I create that?

here is the screen shot of Gparted:

[image]

Comment: As I can see you have not swap partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split the problem into two parts

1. Verify if you have the swap partition
2. Verify if your swap partition is actually used.

ad 1) Partition /dev/sda7 was the most probably supposed to be the swap partition. Most probably it somehow got damaged, as otherwise filesystem would be recognized as swap.

ad 2) Command free shows you how much swap you have

```
free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3906656    1582008    2324648      78656      41176     916644
-/+ buffers/cache:     624188    3282468
Swap:      8892412          0    8892412
```

In this case it shows 8GB of swap, none of it's is used.

You may want to reactivate your swap partition.

1. Make sure that your partition /dev/sda7 does not contain any valuable data (most probably not)
2. Configure type of /dev/sda7 to id 82 (Linux swap / Solaris) you can use both gparted or fdisk to do so.
3. Format /dev/sda7 to be a valid swap `mkswap /dev/sda7`
4. Activate the swap by `swapon /dev/sda7`
5. Additionally modify /etc/fstab to make swap start after every boot. The swap line will probably be already there. You will just need to update UUID received as output of 3.